# Can't get table formatting to be proper!

Tags: tables, formatting

So here's the output I want: (ignore outermost fade border)

[image]

This is the code I enter into LaTex:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Rafael} \\ \cline{3-4}
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}    & $l$ & $r$ \\ \cline{1-4}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Roger} & $L$ & $50,50$      & $80,20$ & $p$\\ \cline{2-4}
                          & $R$  & $90,10$   & $20,80$  & $1-p$\\  \cline{2-4}
                          &  & $q$ & $1-q$\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

and this is the output I get:
[image]

What mistakes am I making???

Comment: The `\hline` etc. are wrong and the last row needs some `\multicolumn` statements, in my point of view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\hline` will use the full width of the table -- use `\cline{x-y}` for specific columns, where `x` is the starting and `y` the final column.

Empty blocks can be achieved with `\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}` (for example)

Consequent equal column types can be squeezed in specification, e.g. 10 centered columns are easy with `\begin{tabular}{*{10}{c}}...`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}


\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|*{4}{c|}c}
\cline{3-4}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{}    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Rafael} \tabularnewline
\cline{3-4} 
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{}    & $l$ & $r$ \tabularnewline 
\cline{1-4}
\multirow{2}{*}{Roger} & $L$ & $50{,}50$      & $80{,}20$ & $p$\tabularnewline 
\cline{2-4}
                      & $R$  & $90{,}10$   & $20{,}80$  & $1-p$\tabularnewline  
\cline{1-4}
\multicolumn{2}{ c}{}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$q$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$1-q$}\tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The real data cells should be formatted with `siunitx` `S` - type, but that's another issue...

Comment: I think the example is a game theory table, hence the data cells seem correct to me...